# How do you store a random key of a dictionary to refresh the dictionary when there are no longer any keys in it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a dictionary wherein a randomized key is generated, and when I click on a button, this randomized key is subsequently removed from the dictionary and stored in a separate list, so that when there are no longer any keys in the dictionary, as the process has been done X number of times, the dictionary is refreshed.

I'm planning on using this dictionary to further my understanding of using random numbers in unity, practicing it through making a 'simple' quiz dictionary. I have tried creating a separate list and refreshing it (which presumably did not work because I did the code wrong I guess...) and experimenting with creating more variables to control it, which also did not work.

```
    public class textScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public static Dictionary<int, string> questionDict = new      Dictionary<int, string>();
    public static Dictionary<int, string> answerDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

public static int randomkey;
public static int removekey;
// You also need to obtain the WRONG values, so you need 'dummy' randomised values
public static int wrongkey;
public static int wrongkey1;
public static int wrongkey2;
public static int wrongkey3;
// You also need to determine the right button
public static int correctbutton;
// In order to obtain question
public static bool nextQuestion;
public void Awake()
{
    // Obtains the right dictionaries
    questionDict = ES2.LoadDictionary<int, string>(control.question.ToString());
    answerDict = ES2.LoadDictionary<int, string>(control.answer.ToString());

}
void Start()
{
    nextQuestion = true;

}

 void Update()
{
    noRepeatAnswers();
    randomiseKeys();
    GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = questionDict[randomkey];
}


void randomiseKeys()
{
    if (nextQuestion == true)
    {

    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < questionDict.Count; i++)
      {
           randomkey = Random.Range(1, questionDict.Count);
           wrongkey = Random.Range(1, questionDict.Count);
           wrongkey1 = Random.Range(1, questionDict.Count);
           wrongkey2 = Random.Range(1, questionDict.Count);
           wrongkey3 = Random.Range(1, questionDict.Count);
        }  

        // Store the above value in a float array

        correctbutton = Random.Range(1, 4);




    }
    followingQuestion();
}

void followingQuestion()
{
    nextQuestion = false;


}
```

The idea is that when you press the 4 buttons ( which use the other integers wrongkey etc.), they will remove this random value (randomkey) from the dictionary before a new question rolls out (through the Boolean), limiting the number of questions until it refreshes, when the value of the keys = null. When I created another list and removed key, the program just went into spasm and crashed.

Comment: What does the code do now? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: `the program just went into spasm and crashed.` I suspect it may have _actually_ thrown an exception. What exception did it throw?

Comment: `I am trying to create a dictionary wherein a randomized key is generated, and when I click on a button, this randomized key is subsequently removed from the dictionary and stored in a separate list, so that when there are no longer any keys in the dictionary, as the process has been done X number of times, the dictionary is refreshed.` This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Take a step back, and explain **why** you want to do this.

Comment: @mjwills currently the code simply goes through the dictionary and that's it. I want it to remove the key and then put keys back in when there are no more keys in the dictionary. Like if there is (1,2,3) in the dictionary. One button clicks removes X (1), the next button click removes either 2,3, in this case 3. etc. until there is no more keys and all 1,2,3 is put back in the dictionary. Does that clarify a bit?

Comment: So your question is how to remove entries from a dictionary?

Comment: Are you aware that neither `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` nor `static` are serializable by the Unity serializer ?

Comment: As a dictionary contains *key-value pairs* you're losing information in this process.

Comment: Sounds like what you actually wanted was a list of questions that are indexed randomly and removed when used.  As @mjwills said, think about the objective of your code rather than your specific implementation.

Comment: @Immersive that's kind of what I was thinking, however what I wanted was for every set of questions to be separate from one-another. Like questions about X and questions about Y. I thought this was only possible using a dictionary.

Comment: @Aybe I was aware of that, which is why with the loading I didn't use playerprefs, but does that stop anything else that I may have missed out ?

Comment: Your question is poorly asked and therefore why it's been down-voted, you should ask what you need to achieve (X) instead of asking why Y does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a Dictionary is to store "Keyed" values, literally as `KeyValuePair<,>`.

From your comments, what you're asking for is a way to group Q&A pairs into categories, then remove those categories.  A Dictionary can be useful in that you can *name* the category, and retrieve a list of Q&A pairs using that name.

```
public class QandA {
    public string Question;
    public string Answer;
}

Dictionary<string, List<QandA> > Trivia;

public InitTrivia() {
    Trivia = new Dictionary<string, List<QandA>>();

    Trivia.Add( "Algebra", new List<QandA> {
        new QandA { Question = "What is 2 + 2?", Answer = "Four" },
        new QandA { Question = "What is 6 x 3?", Answer = "Eighteen" },
    });
}
```

If you want to randomly select a topic (a random element between zero-inclusive and element count-exclusive):

```
using System.Linq;
var category = Trivia.Keys.ElementAt(Random.Range(0, Trivia.Keys.Count));
```

From that topic, randomly select a QandA pair (a random element between zero-inclusive and element count-exclusive):

```
var qaList = Trivia[category];
var qaInstance = qaList[Random.Range(0, qaList.Count)];
```

From there you probably want to remove the QandA from the list so it doesn't get re-asked, and remove any empty lists from the dictionary.

When you want to reset, it's probably easiest to just to re-run your original `init()` code (which will presumably load all the QandA from a save file/serialised source)

Comment: Thanks very much for the response! That's kind of what I want (or what I think is necessary), but my issue is after you call the dictionary, how do you remove the QandA from the list and then get another random value after the question is completed? Like let's say you have What is 2+2 and 4. You set a random.range(0, QandA.count) as a variable (let's say randomkey). After that, when you click the button I want that value (2+2 = 4) to be removed. Currently, when I cause the questions to reload with a Boolean this doesn't work...that's what I'm wondering.